# Get AVRCP and BlueZ to work for controlling phone

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, bluez, pulseaudio, avrcp

not sure if I got everything right so please be a bit patient with me ;-)

I setup my RPi with BlueZ + pulse (on Rasbian) audio working as A2DP receiver and it works like charm with my iPhone and iPad. For my project I would like to implement AVRCP to control the audio player over bluetooth.

In the current stable version or Raspian BlueZ is implemented in version 4.99, the last v4 version is 4.101 and BlueZ 5 is already out.

Did anybody get AVRCP to work and control at least the major functions play/pause, prev and next? I would be so happy to implement that as well!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

how far have you been going on this task?
am doing almost the same,(PandaBoard-ES + iPhone) and am using Bluez4.98-2ubuntu7.
so far you can get the **port** of the iPhone responsible for the AV remote Control, create a **L2CAP** socket and connect your RPi to the device at this port.

until this point you should be able to transfer the music via bluetooth(somehow weird because for this should be used a A2DProfile), any chance, this is working on your Rpi???

Cheers!

Sepp

Comment: I did get my iPhone to work with RPi without any issue regarding the music. This worked without any AVRCP or L2CAP but only A2DP activated. Beside that I wanted to go further and control my iPhone from my RPi (play, pause, volume up/down), for this I thought I needed an AVRCP profile but I did not get it working so far.

Comment: ok, I got it, are you developing this in any kind of language? or scripting language? am doing this with python, so if you are so, could you please let me know what is going on on your terminal when you do something like this:
#unit info 
msg = "\x01\xFF\x30"
socket.send(msg)
answer = socket.recv(1024)
print colored(answer, "green")

Comment: Unfortunately not. I developed in C.

Comment: so... am going  forward (hopefully not on the way to hell), is you are able to upgrade the bluez to 4.101(the last one of the serie 4), then under examples, take a look on the simple-endpoint, there you can see that there is a parameter for the avrcp and as far as I think, you can see the interfaces in d-feet...